# IServiceCollection does not contain a defintion for AddHttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to use HttpClient in my .net core 2.0 project and for that I have injected HttpClient in my controller. But when I am trying to configure httpclient in my startup.cs I am getting this error: "IServiceCollection does not contain a defintion for AddHttpClient". I have already referenced `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;` and `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;` and here is what I am trying to do:

```
services.AddHttpClient<TestController>();
```

It's working fine in other project with same namespaces but here I am getting the error. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aah, I have found the solution. I think `services.AddHttpClient` work with .net core 2.1. So I updated my .net core version to 2.1 and updated the microsoft packages to 2.1 and it starts working.

Comment: I think you have .NET Standard and .NET Core mixed up? Core 3.0 implements Standard 2.1. See the table: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Answer (score 313):

You need to install `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http)

Comment: Make sure to install the correct version for your target framework. e.g. if you are targeting .net core 3.1 then you need to install version 3.1.x of this package. Otherwise, you'll likely get an error like `System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=X.X.X.X`

Comment: I solved it by installing Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly

Comment: Same, @mfa comment save me. Visual Studio does not give a clear message. it was not saying I had the wrong version, was just saying "IServiceCollection does not contain a defintion for AddHttpClient".

Comment: Worked for me on .net6.

Comment: Impressive how hard is to find this, search engines are bloated with useless tutorials and it took me several minutes to find such a simple information. Thank you very much, it works fine with .NET 6 and C# 10.

Comment: Using .NET 8 here, and this is the answer - it's moved since it was in DI extensions!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;` in .net 6.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34406268)

Answer (score -5):

I went through the same error but by adding

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
```

the error states "'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddHttpClient' and no accessible"
and found out that with .net 6 we no longer need to add

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
```

so if anyone comes across the same error, we just do not need to add the HttpClient

Comment: Then how do you get a HttpClient instance from constructor injection ?